# JQuery calendar and MVC datetime submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

We all know about the problems we face when it comes to different UI culture to display dates. But when posting, we also have that problem to since when posting, the ASP.NET MVC doesn't really "automatically" bind the format given into any way it sees fit.

My question is, how can I post back the date in the format of yyyy/MM/dd so it can bind correctly to the model property?

I want to display the date format in the UI format of what the culture is (i.e UK/US etc...) and let the user select the date from the jquery calendar as normal. But only when posting, do I want to make the "correction"

what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same issue, and get it solved by adding an alternate field for the date, which I send to the Controller.

**Helper:**

```
public static CultureInfo UserCultureInfo()
{
    // Retrieves the user culture info based on the browser request
    var userLanguages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

    CultureInfo ci;

    if (userLanguages.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0]);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     }

     return ci;
}
```

**HTML (Razor View):**

```
@{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo curInfo = Helpers.UserCultureInfo();
}

<!-- You need to change the file to be loaded based on the Culture information returned above -->
@Html.Script("DatePicker/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB")

<!-- The hidden field should be the one posted back to the Controller -->
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="" />

<!-- This one is just to display the DatePicker -->
<input type="text" id="myDatePickerField" name="myDatePickerField" />
```

**JS:**

```
$("#myDatePickerField").datepicker({
    altField: "#myDate",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", // The date sent will be in the YYYY-MM-DD format (refer to the HTML code to understand this bit)
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" // As I'm in the UK, I set the default format to DD/MM/YYYY
});
```

This is just a start, an idea on how you can achieve the result expected. Of course you'll need to implement changes to complete it and fit it to your web site.
How you can detect the user locale information and apply it to your solution is a bit more broaden and complex. There are lots of tips and tutorials across the web.

Comment: Thanks for a speedy and nice response MelanciaUK. Question: Where and how do I get/initialize the locale scripts? Also, the altFormat - how does that work? I mean, will it use it when the page posts back to the controller to format the datetime in the format I want so it can be parsed correctly by the binder?. Finally - what is the altField you are referencing? currently I just have it like so: var dateFormatStr = 'yy/mm/dd'
                $('#NextPayDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: dateFormatStr }); which is not what I want obviously.

Comment: When the user selects a date on the `DatePicker`, it will populate the alternate field in the format you've set up `(YYYY-MM-DD)`. Both fields will be posted back to the `Controller`. There you should consider the hidden field as your selected date.

Comment: thanks again, I will give this a bash for sure and give feedback/mark as answer. another question: how would I obtain and load the culture info script?

Comment: When you download the `DatePicker` library, it comes with various locale scripts. You can see I'm loading the `en-GB` in the post `(Razor View)`.

Comment: would it come with MVC 4?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry again my friend - struggling to understand the scripts part - in your example, you are loading the UK script - that's fine but how would that change depending on the culture? any sample on that?

Comment: As I mentioned, this is way more broaden. My solution is more complex than just that. I'm using another script to detect time zone, etc. What the Culture info will return (in this example) is the language: `en-GB`, `en-US`, etc. You just need to replace it in the script file name.